# Spring MVC with Jetty - what is supposed to go in the app-servlet.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, jetty

I am working on a Spring MVC web application, that uses a Jetty HTTP server, which contains a WebAppContext

```
<bean id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server" init-method="start"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="9531" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <bean id="contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
                        <property name="handlers">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                                    <property name="contextPath" value="/" />
                                    <property name="war" value="/etc/WebContent" />
                                    <!-- <property name="copyWebDir" value="true" />  -->
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm trying to figure out where beans are supposed to be defined.  There are basically two choices: my app specific Spring config file (call it "myApp-context.xml") or the servlet Spring config file (call it "myApp-servlet.xml").  The relevant section from the web.xml file is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:jeff/myApp-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So far, so good.  Based on other related questions/answers, I put things like my Spring MVC view resolvers (which is directly related to the webapp) into myApp-servlet.xml, and other app-specific beans like DAOs, entitlements utilities, etc. into myApp-context.xml (which is given as the "contextConfigLocation" in web.xml).  This works fine, the app starts up and everything gets injected correctly, Spring MVC controllers work fine, etc.

What I've noticed, though, is that any beans defined in myApp-servlet.xml (which, according to convention, must exist in the web root dir given that my servlet name is "myApp") are loaded by Spring twice.  Specifically, there is a log message like "Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myApp'", after which point all the beans that were in myApp-servlet.xml are loaded again.

If I move all of those beans from myApp-servlet.xml to myApp-context.xml, leaving myApp-servlet.xml empty (just opening and closing  tags), the app starts successfully (faster this time) and does not create each bean twice.

Yet, Jetty's WebAppContext seems to insist upon there being a myApp-servlet.xml file (if one doesn't exist, the app fails to start).  It also requires that contextConfigLocation be defined and point to a valid Spring config file.

Can anyone help me sort out my configuration?  Leaving myApp-servlet.xml devoid of any bean definition feels right because the app starts faster and without redundant bean initialization, but wrong because the web app context seems to demand it exist.  Putting some beans into myApp-servlet.xml feels right because it would otherwise be empty, but wrong because now those beans are initialized twice, startup takes longer, and the choice of which beans to put there feels arbitrary anyway.  Thanks for any help, and more details/snippets can be provided as needed.

**Edit**:  it's now clear to me the reason these two are different.  myApp-servlet.xml is a servlet-specific Spring config file.  So if that servlet is a Spring MVC servlet, one should put the controllers, etc. in that file.  One could also have myApp2-servlet.xml and myApp3-servlet.xml as well, defining two other servlets in the same container.  All of these will naturally have beans independent from each others' (since they are totally separate web apps).

On the other hand, the myApp-context.xml file contains bean definitions that will be provided to *each* servlet.  That's why DB utilities, entitlements, etc., as Neeme Praks pointed out, should go in that file.  It's quite likely that each web app, while being totally separate in its presentation and function, will need to use some common utilities.  This is the place for those "common" beans to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have a correct setup:

- `myApp-servlet.xml` should contain directly webapp-related beans
- `myApp-context.xml` should contain the business logic beans (e.g. DAOs, entitlements utilities)

As for the reason, why your webapp-related beans are loaded twice - dunno. **They should not be loaded twice**. Maybe you are **reading the log wrong**? Maybe there is some **configuration mistake** that is not obvious from the configuration snippets you provided (full `web.xml`, `myApp-servlet.xml` and `myApp-context.xml` would be useful)?

See also:

- [Spring documentation about DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)
- [How should application+web contexts be organized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4003775/74694)

Comment: Thanks - I can see the problem is that I included myApp-servlet.xml (along with myApp-context.xml) as a value for the contextConfigLocation property in web.xml.  This obviously causes those beans to be loaded twice.  Unfortunately, when I don't include myApp-servlet.xml in contextConfigLocation, I have a different problem (Spring MVC controllers fail to pick up on requests), so I'll need to mess around with it some more.